# How to use an attribute of a directive inside an ng-switch in a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to reference an attribute of a directive in a ng-switch-when attribute in the internal template.

I've cut out some of the complexity, but essentially my html looks like this:

```
<mydirective data-name="foo" data-index="1">Some Text</mydirective>
```

The directive code looks like this:

```
.directive('mydirective', function() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: '@name',
      index: '@index'
    },
    template: '<p>{{name}}-{{index}}</p><div ng-switch-when=\'{{name}}-{{index}}\' ng-transclude></div>'
  };
});
```

When this is run in Chrome, it renders as:

```
<mydirective data-name="foo" data-index="1" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
    <p class="ng-binding">foo-1</p>
    <!-- ngSwitchWhen: {{name}}-{{index}} -->
</mydirective>
```

Note that the "foo" and "1" make it into the `<p>` tag but not into the ngSwitchWhen.

**Edited to add**
What I am hoping to actually see on my page is something like this:

```
<mydirective data-name="foo" data-index="1" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
    <p class="ng-binding">foo-1</p>
    <div ng-switch-when="foo-1">Some Text</div>
</mydirective>
```

Comment: I think the whole approach I'm using here is incorrect. Going to rethink this and come up with a different way of asking about it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can use a expression to print value instead of string value. https://plnkr.co/edit/BtTLhKDZqMTGT9wuETq8

Please check the ngSwitch document
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

*Be aware that the attribute values to match against cannot be expressions. They are interpreted as literal string values to match against. For example, `ng-switch-when="someVal"` will match against the string `"someVal"` not against the value of the expression `$scope.someVal`*

Comment: This is not intended to be an expression, it is a literal string value that I need to place in the ng-switch-when. What I want there is `ng-switch-when="foo-1"`

Comment: Yeah what the docs say is you cannot use expression values in ng-switch-when but directly string.

Answer (score 0):

The variable inside `ng-switch-when=\''` might not be returning what you want.

Try using:

```
ng-switch-when=\'{{name + '-' +index}}\'
```

instead of

```
ng-switch-when=\'{{name}}-{{index}}\'
```

Comment: Was unable to do it. Can you check my plunkr for your edit.